# Recursive Binary Tree Search MakePerfect x=change(x)

Tags: java

I am suppose to write a method makePerfect that could be added to the IntTree class. The method should add nodes until the binary tree is a "perfect" tree. A perfect binary tree is one where all leaves are at the same level. Another way of thinking of it is that you are adding dummy nodes to the tree until every path from the root to a leaf is the same length. A perfect tree's shape is exactly triangular and every branch node has exactly two children. Each node you add to the tree should store the value 0.

An example of before and after calls : [image]

my code works for these cases:

[image]

but fails others. With this method, there is a helper method that is included that we may only call once.

```
// WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
public void makePerfect() {
    overallRoot = makePerfect(overallRoot, 1);
}

private IntTreeNode makePerfect(IntTreeNode root, int lvl) {
    if(root != null) {
        if( lvl < height(root) ) {
            if(root.left == null && root.right != null) {
                root.left = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.left = makePerfect(root.left, lvl + 1);
                root.right = makePerfect(root.right, lvl +1);
            }if(root.right == null && root.left != null) {
                root.right = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.right = makePerfect(root.right, lvl +1);
                root.left =makePerfect(root.left, lvl +1);
            }else if ( root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                root.left = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.right = new IntTreeNode(0);
                lvl++;
            }else {
            root.left = makePerfect(root.left, lvl +1);
            root.right = makePerfect(root.right, lvl +1);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}




// LEAVE THESE METHODS HERE, TO USE AS HELPERS
public int height() {
    return height(overallRoot);
}

private int height(IntTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + Math.max(height(root.left), height(root.right));
    }
}
```

What cases am I not testing for ? Been stuck on this for a while, any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code fails these cases:
[image]

My output is the same as the "name" column, it is not recursing correctly.

Comment: "but fails others." - Show some cases that fail, and what output you are getting for those.

Comment: Which cases does it succeed, and which ones does it fail?

Comment: I have added the cases that my code fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather suspecious:

```
 if( lvl < height(root) )
```

You probably should compute the height not in the recursion, but rather pass the height in as a parameter. Now you just compute the height in every recursion, so it gets messed up, since what you probably intent to do here is to check if the level is equal to the height of the entire tree, not if it is equal to the height of the subtree rooted at the current node.

Comment: hmmmm i see what you are saying, lemme see if that does anything if I compute it outside so its fixed.

Comment: that fixed it except for one condition :(

Comment: @this1lefty No problem at all glad to help:)

Answer (score 3):

```
else if ( root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                root.left = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.right = new IntTreeNode(0);
                lvl++;
```

after calling this ,those new node will never be perfected so you must add a condition here to perfect them if their heightis less than the tree height

```
else if ( root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                root.left = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.right = new IntTreeNode(0);
                lvl++;
if(level <height (root)
makePerfect(root.left, lvl +1);
makePerfect(root.left, lvl +1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct solution for future references.

```
public void makePerfect() {
    int target = height(overallRoot);
    overallRoot = makePerfect(overallRoot,target, 1);
}

private IntTreeNode makePerfect(IntTreeNode root, int target,int lvl) {

    if(root != null) {
        if( lvl < target) {
            if(root.left == null && root.right != null) {
                root.left = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.left = makePerfect(root.left,target, lvl + 1);
                root.right = makePerfect(root.right,target, lvl +1);
            }if(root.right == null && root.left != null) {
                root.right = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.right = makePerfect(root.right,target,lvl +1);
                root.left =makePerfect(root.left,target, lvl +1);
            }else if ( root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                root.left = new IntTreeNode(0);
                root.right = new IntTreeNode(0);
                lvl++;
                if(lvl< target) {
                    makePerfect(root.left,target, lvl +1);
                    makePerfect(root.right, target, lvl +1);
                }
            }else {
            root.left = makePerfect(root.left, target,lvl +1);
            root.right = makePerfect(root.right,target, lvl +1);
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or a much more elegant solution:

```
public void makePerfect() {
    overallRoot = makePerfect(overallRoot, 1);
}

private IntTreeNode makePerfect(IntTreeNode root, int level) {
    if (level <= height()) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new IntTreeNode(0);
        }
        root.left = makePerfect(root.left, level + 1);
        root.right = makePerfect(root.right, level + 1);
    }
    return root;
}
```